# How to create sheets with same structure?

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I'm trying to create a year report in Excel, where every month is represented by a sheet. I'd like every sheet to look exactly the same and I want the corresponding fields to contain exactly the same information/formula. Also, when I decide to change the global 'structure' in the future, I'd like to make these changes only once and let all the month sheets be changed automatically (I now have to do this manually twelve times...).

Is this possible and, if yes, how can I do this?

Comment: one easy way would be to use VBA, whenever you want to change, change the script and run. this way there won't be many manual changes required

Comment: @gaurav5430: That sounds promising. Could you post an answer and be a little bit more specific? Perhaps give me an example...

Comment: I much prefer to have 1 sheet with a drop-down for each month and formulas to pull the corresponding details. That way if you ever want to change the format, you only have to change it once. And most likely you won't be looking at more than one month at a time anyway.

Comment: @guitarthrower: That's true, but I'd like to be able to print the monthly reports, so working with a dropdown doesn't seem the perfect solution to me.

Comment: This is not a question suited to Stack Overflow, it is appropriate for Super User

Comment: @Jeroen. I don't understand how it wouldn't work. In your solution, you switch to a different sheet and print. In mine you change the month in the drop down and print. Same result, better performance, smaller file, easier to make changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have workbooks like that.  The sheets I just copy, then change the month reference.  At the end of the year I copy the workbook and change the date, and archive the old workbook.

Answer (score 0):

Another option (to avoid multiple changes after some sheets have been constructed) is to create a group and make all the changes in one of them. Then ungroup to add data. Then regroup to make changes to already-populated as well as yet-to-be populated sheets.

To group sheets, select the first and last tab with Shift depressed. To ungroup click on a single tab.

[Ref](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/select-one-or-multiple-worksheets-HP010342883.aspx)

`By clicking the tabs of worksheets (or sheets) at the bottom of the window, you can quickly select a different sheet. If you want to enter or edit data on several worksheets at the same time, you can group worksheets by selecting multiple sheets. You can also format or print a selection of sheets at the same time.`

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I didn't know one could do that. Unfortunately, I get an error message when I try to change something in a table. Any solutions for that?